# Run a macro when a pivot table changes

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

Is there any way to detect when a pivot table changes, filters are set, in VBA?

I have a macro I would like to automatically run when the user changes the filters of the pivot table.

Comment: You can use the Worksheet_Change event and check whether Target is intersecting the Pivot Table range.

Comment: @Gareth that would probably work, but the answer from Error 1004 is a lot more elegant

Comment: No, I can't argue with that.  I completely missed that one.  Still, good to learn.

Comment: If the user changes the caption beneath the filter, the `Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate` event is **not** raised. Therefore I suggest the classic `Worksheet_Change` event instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate(ByVal Target As PivotTable)

    'Check if is the right pivot changed
    If Target.Name = "PivotTable1" Then
        ' some code here
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks this worked.
For any one else wondering, where this code goes, paste it into the worksheet where the pivot being watched is.

Answer (score 0):

The other answer is almost elegant, but the `PivotTableUpdate` event is not raised, if some captions are changed:

[image: screenshot of pivot table captions]

If you need an event for **any** change within your pivot table, use following instead within your worksheet's code module:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.PivotTables(1).TableRange2) Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Pivot's TableRange2 Changed"
    End If
End Sub
```