# Refreshing a filter in a table every time slicers update

Tags: excel, vba, pivot, autofilter, slicers

I have a sheet with slicers that refer to a pivot on another sheet. On my sheet with slicers they update a table which references said pivot.

The question is that, when I change the slicer filter, in cover sheet, pre-defined filter is not updating and showing empty rows.

This is what I've tried but nothing seems to do the trick:

```
 Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
   Sheets("FM_Ozet").AutoFilter.ApplyFilter
   Worksheets("FM_Ozet").Range("A2:b100").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>", Operator:=xlFilterValues

End Sub
```

But with this code i need to change any selection from workheet. I would like to apply filter each time when i clicked or select one of slicer options.

thank you.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, maybe try to use Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56342109/run-a-macro-when-a-pivot-table-changes. If the slicer is for the page field in report filter, you use the current page value as the criteria to filter the data in your sheet FM_Ozet. If the slicer is for the page field in row labels, get the value (for criteria) from the cell right under this column of the pivot table.

Comment: I tried every function in there, because of there is no change in Pivot these steps also not affecting. I have pivot table in another sheet, and dashboard/summary in first sheet that build with formulas to read data in pivot sheet. Worksheet_Change event also not working same there is no change in cover sheet.

Comment: Oops... sorry, I thought that you want a certain process to run when in sheet BLA you click an item in a slicer (where this slicer is connected to a pivot table in sheet BLO). Anyway, AFAIK clicking a slicer will trigger Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate. Example : there is a slicer in sheet BLA. There is no pivot table in sheet BLA, the slicer in sheet BLA is connected to a pivot table in sheet BLO. In sheet BLO module, there is Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate sub. So say, while sheet BLA active, a user click an item in the slicer, this will trigger Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate in sheet BLO module to run.

Comment: @karma thank you, the way you said done, i will share full answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I thought i need to put code in cover sheet, but the answer is need to put in Pivot sheet.

```
   Private Sub Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate(ByVal Target As PivotTable)
    If Target.Name = "PivotTable5" Then
    Sheets("FM_Ozet").AutoFilter.ApplyFilter
    Worksheets("FM_Ozet").Range("A2:b100").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>", Operator:=xlFilterValues
   End If
   End Sub
```

thank you.